# state updated in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react js. in that array stored in my state I update that array in user action. then I check the sum of this array if it goes beyond one I am showing error. now problem happened that it shows the error still it updates the value

```
 updateValuePercent = key => {
    let MixDataTemp = [...this.state.MixData];
    let MixData = [...MixDataTemp];

let reduceValue = 0.005 / 4;
MixData.map(data => {


        data.mix.map(name => {

          if (name.pk === key.pk) {

                name.volume = name.volume - 0.005;

          } else {

            name.volume = name.volume - reduceValue;

            } 
          return name;
        });
        return data;

    });
  let nwSum = updatedData

      .map(data => data.mix)
      .map(data => data.volume)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
if (nwSum <= 1) {//condition to update the data
      this.setState({
        MixData: updatedData,
        MixError: ''
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ MixError: 'values can not go beyond one' });//showing error on page still updating the state
    }
}
```

I know what I did is a mutable I shouldn't do it but at least it shouldn't my state at least m taking immutable copy of the state

EDIT 1:
here is my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/vihang_16/pen/XeERKq)

Comment: This is really confusing, can you clarify the problem?

Comment: updated the code let me know it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to show the `MixData` value you have in state, I'd explicitly tell React that it's null (or some value that makes it clear to the user that it cannot be incremented) i.e.:

```
if (nwSum <= 1) {
  this.setState({
    MixData: updatedData,
    MixError: ''
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
   MixData: null,
   MixError: 'values can not go beyond one'
  });
}
```

It looks like your in your `else` block you are actually only returning a value for `MixError` in `state`. Based on your code, I wouldn't expect to see any value for `MixData` since it's not being copied over. To copy over the previous value of `MixData` you'd need to use the spread operator i.e.:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  MixError: 'values can not go beyond one'
});
```

Best of luck!

Comment: but one thing state should not update with the new value right?because am not updating it

Comment: Based on your code `state` should not have a value for `MixData` because you do not supply one in `this.setState`. It would be easier to debug if you could provide a fiddle however.